# Why vim's d operator is misbehaving?

Tags: linux, vim

Few days ago I decided to use the Vim text editor... playing around with the vimtutor I found something very rare with the **d** operator; Vim session:

### Case 1

**before:** The Quick Red F`o`x Jumps Over the Lazy Brown Dog 
**after :**     The Quick Red F  Jumps Over the Lazy Brown Dog

results: as expected.

### Case 2

*Placing the cursor in the last character of a word.*

**before:** The Quick Red Fo`x` Jumps Over the Lazy Brown Dog 
**after :**     The Quick Red Fo Over the Lazy Brown Dog

results: **de** deletes the "x Jumps" substring.

### Case 3

*Placing the cursor in the last character of the last word.*

**before:** The Quick Red Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Brown Do`g` 
**after :**     The Quick Red Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Brown Do

results: as expected.

---

Please note that:

- In both cases I'm using the `de` command.
- **after:** reflects the changes after applying the `de` command.
- The highlighted part represent the cursor position in the editor.

Questions:

1. Is this a bug?
2. Am I doing something wrong?
3. What is happening?

Vim version: version 7.3.50; Modified by Gentoo-7.3.50

Comment: `e` moves to the _next end_ of a word. If you are already on the end of a word, that means the end of the _next word_. So that's expected behavior.

Comment: Place your cursor on the `x` and type `e`. It will move to the end of `jumps`

Comment: If you want to delete to the end of the current word under the cursor, use `dw`

Comment: If you are already at the end of a word, you can use `x` to delete that single character.

Comment: so if I'm at the end of a word, `e` takes me to the end of the next word, right? but, what if I'm at the end of the last word? ... it works as expected! ... :S this is not a congruent behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pressing <kbd>e</kbd>, vim takes you to the *end of the word*. If the cursor is on the `x` in fox, you are *already there*, so <kbd>e</kbd> takes to the *next* end of a word.

Thus, <kbd>de</kbd> will delete `jumps` as well.

Comment: @Kira I'm not sure about case 3. The same happens when you do `dl`, even though you can't use `l` anymore to go more to the right. Apparently vim has some idea of "going beyond" and deletes as much as it can to stay consistent with what it would do if there *was* another word.

Answer (score 6):

When you are already at the end of word, <kbd>de</kbd> will delete to the end of next word.
<kbd>d</kbd> is a *operator* command. It accepts a *motion* command(<kbd>e</kbd> or others).
When you press <kbd>e</kbd> at the end of word, you can see that behavior is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that de is 2 commands `d` deletes. `e` is end of word.

Issuing `e` at the end of one word jumps to the end of the next word. So de deletes from the current position to the end of the next word. You might want to try `dw` or `daw`

See also `:help e` and `:help d`